# PHP - Change Variable Name

Tags: php, file, replace

I have two 'includes' php pages, Page 1 and Page 2. 
Page 1 displays contents for today, Page 2 displays contents for yesterday. 
I set a cronjob to copy contents of Page 1 to Page 2 every 0:00am daily.

On the main page (the page that contains this page 1 and page 2), I have:

```
$date = date("d/m", strtotime("now"));
$dateyes = date("d/m", strtotime("-1 day"));
```

Then on Page 1, I have:

```
echo $date;
```

On Page 2, what I need is:

```
echo $dateyes;
```

But due to the cronjob, I only get

```
echo $date;
```

on that Page 2. Is there a way I can change that $date to $dateyes on that Page 2?

Comment: [**Variable variables**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) might be useful to you

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure how copying a php script from day to day should work in practice, but if need this pattern for some reason, simply replace your current `echo $date;` to `echo $is_page1 ? $date : $dateyes;`

Where `$is_page` a variable that check which page is loaded via something like:

```
$is_page1 = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] === 'page1.php';
```

Or:

```
$is_page1 = basename(__FILE__) === 'page1.php';
```

Comment: I use this script to do the copying, 
    $old = 'page2.php';
    $new = 'page1.php';
    copy($new, $old);
then I schedule it using cronjob to run daily.

Comment: I have gotten what I needed.I'm not really a strong programmer at this time. Your answer was a bit too complex for me to understand but a statement from your answer "check which page is loaded" made me to have a different new approach, and the new thoughts provided the perfect solution I needed. Take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
On the mainpage.php, I checked if "dateyes" already exists in page2.php, if it already exists, script does nothing but if "dateyes" does not exist, my script searches for "date" in that page2.php and since what I needed on page2.php was "dateyes", I replaced "date" with "dateyes".

On mainpage.php

```
$datetod = date("d/m", strtotime("now"));
$dateyes = date("d/m", strtotime("-1 day"));

$file = file_get_contents('../includes/page2.php');

if(strpos($file, "dateyes") !== false){} 
else {
$str=str_replace("datetod", "dateyes",$file);
file_put_contents('../includes/page2.php', $str);
}
```

So I no longer worry about the cronjob which automatically copies $date from page1.php to page2.php everyday at 0:00am because the first person who loads/views the page (mainpage.php) is automatically going to change the $date in page2.php to $dateyes which is what I need.

Comment: `$file = file_get_contents('../includes/page2.php');` sounds really fishy to me, I'm still uncertain what's your use case here but I think you are approaching the problem in a wrong way. You shouldn't really alter the scripts like this, if you need the script to do something different you include that logic in the script itself...

Comment: Maybe my question was not very clear.

I have mainpage.php, page1.php and page2.php.Mainpage.php is the main page, page1.php and page2.php are includes files and I use Javascript on mainpage.php to toggle between page1.php and page2.php.

Secondly, page1.php has contents with today's date, page2.php is supposed to have contents with yesterday date, but due to cronjob I set to copy page1.php contents to page2.php, the contents are copied but then the date on page2.php now becomes today's date instead of yesterday.

Comment: So the code I found and shared, what it does now is to get the contents of page2.php and change that date on page2.php back to yesterday's date.